# How to colour cells if strike through [google spreadsheet]

Tags: javascript

I'm preparing a spreadsheet in which i'd like that, if someone strikes through a cell (text in it), the colour of that cell changes. The range of cells should be the entire worksheet, as any cell could be strike-through. I've tried to build a function, but i'm not really a developer, so help would be greatly appreciated.. ;)

```
function lineThrough() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //first sheet
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, lc);
  var results = range.getFontLines();

  for (var i = 0; i < lr; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < lc; j++) {
      if (results[i][j] == 'line-through') {
        var color = sheet.getRange(lr, lc - 1).setBackground('green');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone who could help me out on this one?

Thanks!

Simon